# jquery change browser tab title when click on link in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a index page with 2 iframes in it. when I click on a link in iframe 2 a page will be opened in iframe 1. Now as an extra I would like to change the browser tab title when you click on that link in iframe2.

I know how to change the browser title tab with the following script but that does only work when it is on the index page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#link1').click(function(){
$('head title').text('HelloWorld'); 
});
});
</script>

<a id="link1" href="home.html" target="iframe1">Home</a>
```

Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        $('head title', window.parent.document).text('HelloWorld');
    });
});
</script>
```

Home

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Markus!
I was able to use your solution in my jquery application, but I used it inside a function because the title can gain two values ​​depending on the value selected in the radio input.

```
$.fn.relacionamento = function() {
if ($("input[name=f_exclusivo]:checked").val() == 0) { 
    $('head title', window.parent.document).text('Titulo 01');
} else { 
    $('head title', window.parent.document).text('Titulo 02');
  }
};
$("input[name=f_exclusivo]").click(function(){ $().relacionamento(); });
```